# Jsoup cleaner version 1.12.1 returns a value other than version 1.11.2

Tags: jsoup

I have a Junit test that checks the next line `"<iframe src=http://xss.rocks/scriptlet.html < asd"` and use `Whitelist.none()`.

```
Jsoup.clean("<iframe src=http://xss.rocks/scriptlet.html < asd", Whitelist.none());
```

Jsoup cleaner version 1.11.2 returns empty string.
Jsoup cleaner version 1.12.1 returns "< asd".
I can’t understand why such a change. Perhaps in version 1.11.2 there was a bug that was fixed. But I did not find information about such a bug. will anyone tell me which of this is true and on what basis?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the changelog for 1.12.1 and found this likely [change](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/1a84ce3b0e3df1018088c59b7c4484df181a2fdb/CHANGES#L90):

> Improvement: if a start tag is missing a > and a new tag is seen with a <, treat that as a new tag. (This differs
>       from the HTML5 spec, which would make at attribute with a name beginning with <, but in practice this impacts too
>       many pages.
>
> https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/797

I think that the response is a pretty reasonable (and definitely safe) interpretation of the malformed input. And to be specific, the actual [output](https://try.jsoup.org/~0ja8QazTyolmbd3K0lKWh6SiJ4U) is:

```
&lt; asd
```

Which means it's safe to render without fear of any XSS attacks.